# Performance slow down after upgrade to Postgres 9.4

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, vmware, postgresql-9.4

We experience significant performance degradation(~4-5 times for random queries) after upgrading our PostgreSQL servers to version 9.4. Previously we ran versions 9.1 and 9.3. I set up version 9.4 to run in parallel with the previous version as a cluster. Then I did pg_dump 9.3 → pg_restore 9.4. Everything else on these servers stayed the same. I even used the same postgresql configuration (see below).

---

```
shared_buffers = 2400MB
temp_buffers = 12MB
work_mem = 4MB
maintenance_work_mem = 64MB
synchronous_commit = off
checkpoint_segments = 20
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.8
effective_cache_size = 8000MB
geqo_effort = 9
autovacuum_max_workers = 4
autovacuum_naptime = 45s
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor = 0.16
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor = 0.08
```

---

The server has 24Gb RAM. VmWare host doesn’t oversubscribe memory and doesn’t use memory ballooning. Our storage is powered by equalogic and is FAR from reaching its bandwidth capacity. There is no swapping going on neither on the server nor on VmWare host. The ONLY difference is that now the database is running in PostgreSQL 9.4.

So my questions are:

- Has anyone experienced similar symptoms after the upgrade to 9.4?
- Is there anything obviously wrong with my configuration? Again the
  same     used to work well for PG 9.3.
- Were there any changes in 9.4 related to disk access and usage
  pattern, memory access & usage pattern?
- Can  memory mapped files cause an issue?
- Can it be sitting waiting on the OS to sync disk and memory but the OS doesn’t do it immediately? And why is this not happening in 9.3?

Environment: Ubuntu Linux server 14.04 running under VmWare.

The process in "htop” looks like doing nothing waiting on disk however the disk is very responsive whenever other processes access it at the same time.

Comment: Did you vacuum your tables after the conversion?  I have something in my head that says that that's necessary.  Can you give more detail about the "significant performance degradation"?  Can you quantify it?  Are there certain operations which are slow but others are not?

Comment: Did you run `ANALYZE` after the import ?

Comment: We run vacuum regularly especially after large updates and we have auto-vacuum in place. The config worked fine while on Postgresql9.3. After installing Postgres9.4 while keeping the same config we've noticed a SIGNIFICANT slow down as 4-5 times for random queries.

Comment: try to VACUUM ANALYZE after upgrade.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming within the scope defined in the help center. Better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/ IMHO.